# Hadoop Dedoop Application unable to contact Hadoop Namenode : Getting "Unable to contact Namenode" error

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, war, hdfs

I'm trying to use the Dedoop application that runs using Hadoop and HDFS on Amazon EC2. The Hadoop cluster is set up and the Namenode JobTracker and all other Daemons are running without error.

But the war Dedoop.war application is not able to connect to the Hadoop Namenode after deploying it on tomcat.

I have also checked to see if the ports are open in EC2.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Amazon AWS, I highly recommend using Amazon Elastic Map Reduce. Amazon takes care of setting up and provisioning the Hadoop cluster for you, including things like setting up IP addresses, NameNode, etc.

If you're setting up your own cluster on EC2, you have to be careful with public/private IP addresses. Most likely, you are pointing to the external IP addresses - can you replace them with the internal IP addresses and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some lines of the Stacktrace from Tomcat's log files?

Dedoop must etablish an SOCKS proxy server (similar to ssh -D port username@host) to pass connections to Hadoop nodes on EC2. This is mainly because Hadoop resolves puplic IPS to EC2-internal IPs which breaks MR Jobs submission and HDFS management.

To this end Tomcat must be configured to to etablish ssh connections. The setup procedure is described [here](http://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/howto_dedoop#socks).